# data binding for reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Sorry for my questions , I'm very new with angular and I'm so lost with this thing.

I need to make a function to edit my users.
So I have to click on edit and have the same form as create but populated with users informations.

Can you help me to make the function good.

Update:

I update my new version without the ngModel,
I want to use patchValue() , but I don' know where and what do to save the new data type by the user and update the parent component

Html

```
<div class="manage-content">
  <div class="title">
    <mat-icon class="user-icon">how_to_reg</mat-icon>
    <h3>Edit a user</h3>
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()">
    <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
      <input id="firstName" matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="f_name"#f_name>
      <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('f_name')">
        The first name you've entered is malformed.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
      <input id="middleName" matInput placeholder="Middle name" formControlName="m_name" #m_name>
      <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('m_name')">
        The middle name you've entered is malformed.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
      <input id="lastName" matInput placeholder="Last name" formControlName="l_name" #l_name>
      <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('l_name')">
        The last name you've entered is malformed.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
      <input id="email" matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"  #email>
      <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldInvalid('email')">
        The email you've entered is malformed.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="cta-btn">
      <button mat-raised-button class="createUserBtn" color="primary" type="submit" (click)="onCloseConfirm()">Update user</button>
      <button mat-raised-button class="createUserBtn" color="warn" type="submit" (click)="onCloseCancel()">Cancel</button></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can I have to use to update the form with submit?

parentComponemt.ts(just a part who open the dialog editUser)

```
  openEditDialog(user): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditUserDialogComponent, {
      width: '30%', disableClose: true, data:  user
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog Closed ${result}`);
      this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data];
      console.log(this.dataSource.data);
      this.dialogResult = result;
    })
  }
```

editUser.ts

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, public dialog: MatDialog, public thisDialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditUserDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.selectedUser = data;
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      f_name: [this.selectedUser.name, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)])],
      m_name: [this.selectedUser.m_name, Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(100)])],
      l_name: [this.selectedUser.l_name, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)])],
      email: [this.selectedUser.email, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')])]
    });
  }


  isFieldInvalid(field: string) {
    return (
      (!this.form.get(field).valid && this.form.get(field).touched) ||
      (this.form.get(field).untouched && this.formSubmitAttempt)
    );
  }

  onUpdate() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      f_name: this.form.value.f_name ,
      m_name: this.form.value.m_name,
      l_name: this.form.value.l_name,
      email: this.form.value.email
    });
    console.log(this.form.value); // the log is what I want , but How update my parent component table ?
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using reactive forms you can use the formControlNames for populating the input fields as you wish, for example

In your `component.ts` first, determine if you are in edit mode or not then you can do something like this:

```
initForm() {
let firstName = '';
if (editMode) {
firstName = "value of first name you get from backend or in some other way";
}
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      f_name: [firstName, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)])]

    });
}
```

So if you're not in edit mode then the field will be empty as the `if` condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same component to save user details and edit user details.
You have to create two routes using the same component. And if you are using edit route then just bellow code.

```
this.form.patchValue({
   f_name: 'Test First Name',
   m_name: 'Test Middle Name',
   l_name: 'Test Last Name',
   email: 'Test Email',
});
```

**OR**

```
const user = {
       f_name: 'Test First Name',
       m_name: 'Test Middle Name',
       l_name: 'Test Last Name',
       email: 'Test Email',
    }

this.form.patchValue(user);
```

Comment: I update my code , can you help me and show me what do and where ?

Comment: No it's not the same component , I have good console.log under the editComponent but I don't know how to pass it to parent

Comment: could you please create stackblitz demo so I can help you better?

Comment: I have too much data in my app, if I do a demo, I have 4 hours long to type it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but,
another way of setting a value of a form control in a reactive form is:

```
EditMethod()
{
this.form.get("formControlName").setValue("the value you get from your back end");
}
```